Extruding solid mesh
I 3d scanned an object, and built a nice mesh. I want to create a piece of plastic that holds this object, but that lets you slide it in and out. I could do this by taking the object, 'extruding' the solid along a path, and then using the result as a tool to cut into a rectangle.
I cannot figure out a clean way to do this in Blender. I can load the mesh, then in edit mode extrude the faces, and it looks approximately correct. But the resulting mesh has all sorts of problems, and is very complicated, and won't load cleanly in other software.
Is there a go-to method of extruding a solid? It is as if you are moving a 3d object through space, and keeping track of the outline of where the object was. It is just a simple line that I want to use right now.
[Edit: Added more details below, thanks for the feedback.]

I inserted a mesh after aligning in CloudCompare (by fitting a plane) from my scanner software's output (CrealityScan)

I remeshed (voxel mode) using the object data properties (ie, not a modifier), to reduce the detail
Turned on x-ray

Hit A to select all points
Extrude edges
Select Orientation: Global
Enter coordinates for desired extrusion


Remesh, again, in voxel mode to try to normalize the shape


When prepping this example, that last step seemed to be crucial, in terms of what I am exporting to other programs. It helps a lot if I remesh. But that leaves this problem/issue:
There is weird pitting in the top of this shape, which shows up after the extrude, but not before.

What is the cause of this, and is there anything I can do to fix it? It looks like some holes in the mesh. It looks like a shrink wrap of another surface above this one would help, but I did a bunch of experimentation with that, and it seemed like it would result in weird distribution of points over the surface.
So, final questions:

Please critique the steps I took, and let me know if I am missing some concepts or details in my approach
Is there a cleaner way to accomplish something like this
Why are there weird artifacts on the side, before the last remesh?
Why are there weird pitting artifacts?
How could I get rid of these artifacts?

It appears like it is something to do with inverted normals (which I can see by enabling "Face Orientation" in the view. The remesh seems to fix lots of the inverted normals on the sides - except where the pitting occurs. Any insights on this?

Why don't you just use all sorts of solutions to fix those "all sorts of problems"?  :D What I am trying to say is you should provide all the specifics, share screenshots and sketches of desired result if you want any meaningful help. I think you should edit the question and provide more info about the specifics for this question to be possible to answer.

Hello and welcome. As it stands this question is unanswerable and was put on hold for lack of essential details to understand the issue. Risking stating the obvious, only you have access to your scene, so unless you describe it thoroughly you alone know your exact setup, settings and what steps you took to arrive where your are now. Describe the issue in detail, add images of relevant settings and user interface, with the [edit] button above. Don't post comments or ask a new question, editing will automatically queue it for reopening review.

Thanks for the gentle and helpful guidance! Resubmitted.

How does this differ from using a 2d shape?

Why not just grab half of the object and moving?

@DanielMöller how would that help? I want the full volume of the mesh that the 2d inhabits at any point along the path. You will notice in the final result in the final screenshot above, that there is a full 3d shape that is not the same as a 2d profile extruded.

You're describing a 4d shape. That makes little to no sense. If you select half of the model (which is symmetric) and grab it, you create a 3d shape that fills the entire path with the entire volume.

@DanielMöller no, I am not describing a 4d shape. If you cut the shape and then merely joined in between, that would not achieve my goal.

So I guess you still haven't explained what you want properly.

Start by making a flat outline of the section you want to extrude:

Click "object" menu at the top, "convert" to "curve" (or draw it as a curve instead of a mesh)
Then create a path curve:

Go to geometry nodes for the "path" and use this node setup (where "cube" is the name of the outline object):

The shade flat is optional.
Alternatively, instead of geometry nodes you can use the "bevel" option in the "data" tab of the path:


Thank you for the kind guidance. I am comfortable if the initial object is 2d, like in your example; my question is how you extrude a 3d object along a path like this. (This may not be the correct concept; it is more like a sweep perhaps.)

It's hard to tell exactly what your process is from your description, but I think you may benefit from using a convex hull conversion.
Let's say you start with this:

After you've extruded the solid along a path, as you say, you end up with a non-printable mesh:

We can already see some planes clipping through each other.
Now we apply the convex hull by going to edit mode and selecting Mesh -> Convex Hull from the tool bar to the top-left of the editor.

This creates a sort "imprint" of the mesh as if it no concavities anywhere. Think of it like stretching a rubber sheet very taut over the entire surface of the mesh.
This convex hull mesh should be printable.
There is probably some tidier way of creating a "sheath" for your mesh, but this may be a good-enough quick and dirty way of getting what you want.

Thanks for the info. This is indeed a good way if the object itself underneath is convex. But if you think of something like a spoon, the convex hull here will bridge between the tip of the handle and the rounded edge, which will result in a very not-spoon like spot at the bottom of the hole. I since added a lot more detail to my question.
